# Dimens.xml values supporting All Devices

Tags: android, multiscreen

Hello guys i know this is an old question but my requirement is different
i searched a lot and all answers are outdated not for xxxhdpi and tablets

I always create a new layout of each different screen and place it in respective folder it all works fine but in every project doing every layout is such a pain .so i came across the concept of dimens concept where you can place  margins in dimens.xml in different values folder and our app will take it based on screen size

What i need is what are the exact folders i need to take and what should be the percentage of values in each folder some thing like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361285/android-xml-layout-for-all-devices-small-normal-large-xlarge-etc) by salman

And if i give margin like

```
 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_300"
```

> If that button comes to centre in small screen ,it should also come in centre in xxxhdpi screen or any other device

and in dimens i will write some thing  like this

```
 <dimen name="dim_3">4.5dp</dimen>
```

i need answer in this format

### folder name     and  percentage

values-sw480dp       2%

values-mdpi           1%

values-ldpi            0.75%

etc

thanks in advance

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: there % is not given

Comment: try http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: i need % ,i know folder names